# PHP session_write_close() keeps sending a set-cookie header

Tags: php, session, cookies

In my framework, I make a number of calls to session_write_close().

Let's assume that a session has been initiated with a user agent. The following code...

```
foreach($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
}
```

...will send the following request header to the browser:

```
Set-Cookie    PHPSESSID=bv4d0n31vj2otb8mjtr59ln322; path=/
              PHPSESSID=bv4d0n31vj2otb8mjtr59ln322; path=/
```

There should be no Set-Cookie header because, as I stipulated, the session cookie has already been created on the user's end. But every call to session_write_close() after the first one in the script above will result in PHP instructing the browser to set the current session again.

This is not breaking my app or anything, but it is annoying. Does anyone have any insight into preventing PHP from re-setting the cookie with each subsequent call to session_write_close?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be that with every subsequent call to session_start(), PHP re-sets the session cookie to its own SID and sends a Set-Cookie response header. But why??

Comment: I answered this with a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046570/php-save-session-when-using-session-write-close/16576572#16576572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not recommend doing so, and there were [bunch of bugs submitted for this](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38104). Since they think it's not a good practice - this is the bug that is not going to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I agree with the last commenter there who asserts that it is completely valid to use multiple session_start/session_write_close blocks throughout ones code. My site -- which is ajaxed the eff out -- will totally lock up if sessions aren't being explicitly closed.

Comment: So is the only way around this to implement custom session cookies?

Comment: Looks like that... ALthough if everything is working OK without it - I would leave default implementation...

Answer (score 2):

Almost every answer I found on SO says to just do a `session_write_close()` and `session_start()` over and over again...some even disable cookies with ini_set temporarily...this seems to be a very bad approach. The PHP authors provided a very clear, best-practice, path to injecting your own way of handling the sessions using `session_set_save_handler`.

I have created an example on another post that shows how you can replace your `session_start()` with `Session::start()` and replace `session_write_close()` with `Session::save()`.  The class is a non-blocking (a user can have concurrent requests) class implemented for PHP 5.4+. In fact, it's just a tweaked version of PHP's example class.

While my example is PHP 5.4+, the same method works in older versions of PHP with callback methods instead of an interface implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993746/482256

Answer (score 1):

session_write_close just close session and write data
while session_start send cookies
if your don`t want send session cookie your mustn't call session_start