# Is "Check if USER logged in system" using SESSIONS in PHP are make the all website/system slower?

Tags: php, session

my website/systems/cms that i build using sessions for authrize , i have been told that its make very very slow the site when i get 150++++ people on my site , this is true ?

Should i make the "Check if USER logged in " function without use sessions?

And also in my main file called - session.php i have session_start(); and that file session.php included in every other files in cms , all of them , so its make it very slow ?
Should i remove that session start and use other way?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use the required data only in session variables. Using unnecessary data in session may consume more memory.

As you said your website is slow when the users are 150++++
This may depend on your server speed

Comment: I didnt understand yet , when i using session start in all of my pages its slow the website ? and when should i use ses_write_close() ?

Comment: If you need any session related data in any php pages, then include the session.php file in that pages only don't include it in remaining pages.

Comment: ok all my website need to be with session_start becuase my user_login_check using this way to analyze if the user already logged in : if(isset($_SESSION['user_login_sting'])){}

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046570/php-save-session-when-using-session-write-close